# ASP .NET 5 (vNext) debugging, best practices

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, asp.net-core

In previous ASP.NET, I add project folder in local IIS, edit *.cshtml and can refresh page in browser for view changes.

In ASP.NET 5 (I not found how debug in local IIS, not IIS Express). 
If I run debug in VS with IIS Express, i see page on localhost:12345 (vNext web server). But if stop debug vNext web server stop too.

How in vNext edit *.cshtml as in previous ASP.NET (without running debug mode in VS)?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish you ASP.NET 5 app to local(or external) IIS via publish options (right click on project and publish). You need to specify few settings (which framework version you use for example) in the process.
You need to add next line in your project.json file under commands section:

```
"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --ASPNET_ENV Development --server=Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls=http://localhost:5000",
```

In order to use this you will need to include some nuget packages under dependencies section in same json file:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-beta8",
```

As i recall, you can even skip this publishing and achive your goal with command prompt. Navigate to your project folder via command prompt and run next command (notice name of the command is same as name you declared in project.json file):

```
dnx web
```

If everything is went ok, you should be able to navigate to you page(http://localhost:5000 in this case) and changes made in views will be visible.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand you correctly, i need publish (or dnx web) every time after edit *.cshtml?

Comment: Nope, you publish or run dnx web command only once. Then go to the source folder of the site and change whatever you like. You should be able to view all changes after refresh.